# .NET 6 Console App cannot access network drives even with NeworkCredentials

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

I have a app that I need to pull files, convert them to a new drive.  When I run this locally, it works great (as is the case all the time lol)  We move this out to a job server and it keeps throwing errors when trying to access the drives.

[image]

here is the code I'm using to pull the files and process them then copy it to new directory.

```
async Task CopyDirectoryWithThrottleAsync(string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory, int maxConcurrency, int batchSize)
{
    SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency);
    List<List<string>> batches = SplitIntoBatches(subDirectories, batchSize);

    foreach (List<string> batch in batches)
    {
        List<Task> copyTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (string directory in batch)
        {
            folderCounter++;
            copyTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await throttler.WaitAsync();

                try
                {
                    string relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(sourceFilePath, directory);
                    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(convertedFilePath, relativePath);

                    if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

                    int SourceCount = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Length;
                    int DestinationCount = Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath).Length;

                    if (SourceCount > DestinationCount)
                    {
                        foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
                        {

                            fileInFolderCount++;
                            string completedFilePath = Path.Combine(convertedFilePath, relativePath);
                            string convertedFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + ".mp3";
                            var CompletedFileName = Path.Combine(completedFilePath, convertedFileName);

                            if (!File.Exists(CompletedFileName))
                            {
                                var fileWebRequest = (FileWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filePath);
                                fileWebRequest.Credentials = theNetworkCredential;


                                using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(filePath))
                                {
                                    using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(CompletedFileName, reader.WaveFormat, 128))
                                    {
                                        reader.CopyTo(writer);
                                    }
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("Saved file {0}", convertedFileName);
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileInFolderCount += DestinationCount;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error saving file.  Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.Release();
                }
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(copyTasks);
    }
}
```

Any idea as to why I keep getting an error message like this:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure if I'm implementing the NetworkCredentials correctly or not but it appears I am, but I could be wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the paths?the message indicates it haven't found any file with the path you provided